# Javascript regex to exclude if inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to split an expression string on the characters +*() but I need to only split there if they are not inside brackets. I am struggling to create the correct regex for this task.

Example:

```
.N.TESTARRAY[INT1+2] + ONLINE * STACKOVERFLOW
```

I would like this to produce an array such as:

```
[ ".N.TESTARRAY[INT1+2]" , "ONLINE" , "STACKOVERFLOW" ]
```

Currently my regex splits on the characters +*()[]

```
split(/(\+|\*|\[|\]|\(|\))/g)
```

Because I split on the square brackets as well, I then loop through the array and merge anything inside the brackets. I think this is clunky though and would like to move it all into the regex.

```
function mergeInnerBrackets(tokens) {
        var merged = [];
        var depth = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if(tokens[i] == "[") {
                depth++;
                merged[merged.length-1] += "[";
            } else if(tokens[i] == "]") {
                depth--;
                merged[merged.length-1] += "]";
            } else if(depth > 0) {
                merged[merged.length-1] += tokens[i];
            } else {
                merged.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        return merged;
}
```

I am using JavaScript and need to be able to support back to IE8. I also read something about being able to do this with negative-look behinds but I saw that JavaScript doesn't support that.

Comment: What about nested `[...]` constructs? Do you expect any?

Comment: I'd advise using services like http://www.regexr.com/ to simplify composing of regular expressions.

Comment: For your purposes is there reliably whitespace between the delimiters and none in the values you want split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can string also be like `.N.TEST[INT1+2] + ON[INT1] * ON[INT2]` ? I'd rather use [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/xA8bN0/2).

```
\s*[+*)(](?![^[]*])\s*
```

If the string can contain more than one pair of `[`...`]`

```
var str = '.N.TEST[INT1+2] + ON[INT1] * ON[INT2]';
console.log(str.split(/\s*[+*)(](?![^[]*])\s*/));
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3hzwdxnz/)

Comment: Oh wow, I didnt even think to test Royi's answer with brackets later in the expression. This one works better for my needs, thanks!

Comment: Also thanks for showing me http://regex101.com, super handy with the explanations.